F-statistic comparision.
My goal is to find a good combination of features for a machine learning algorithm. I have two multivariate normal distributions and I want to find out what combination of features (x or y or both) is ideal to discriminate between them. For that I first calculate the F-statistic of both distributions only with the features x and y alone (ANOVA). Then I calculate the F-Statistic with both features (MANOVA). I already got some good results out of that. Let's look at this diagram with two multivariate normal distributions.
Notice that the x-feature on its own seems to be quite useless but the combination of both features returns a way higher F-statistic.
This looks like a good result to me. Now I have another example. Here I now have 2 normal Distributions with completely uncorrelated features. This time I don't really understand the result. For every combination of features I get an F-statistic that has very similar values. This should not be the case as the diagonal distance between both means is higher in 2D-Space than in the one dimensional case. The variance stays the same in every direction around the mean.
Why is that so? Are there other methods to find out the most discriminatory combination?
For the calculations I used the statsmodels MANOVA object and the sklearn f_classif function in python.
